# Missing 0xF and 0x16 when binary data through virtual serial port pair created by socat

Tags: serial-port, socat

I have used following command to create a pair for serial port and trying to send binary data across them.

```
sudo socat -d -d pty,link=/dev/tty.vcp0,raw,echo=0,user=myusername,group=staff pty,link=/dev/tty.vcp1,raw,echo=0,user=myusername,group=staff
```

However, even I try to send follow binary file

data.bin

```
0x16 0x16 0x16 0x16 0x16 0x16
```

(basically just a file with 6 bytes, each byte has value 0x16)

by

```
cat /dev/tty.vcp0 > recv.bin
```

and

```
cat data.bin > /dev/tty.vcp1
```

And what I get is just 3 bytes of 0x16 instead of 6.

Similar thing happen on byte 0xF. If I send a binary file with 6 bytes of 0xF, I can't received any single byte.

Anyone know what is causing the missing 0x16 and 0xF?
How can I transfer binary data which contain 0x16 and 0xF?

Other test case:

**Test case 1**

Send:

```
0x16 0x16 0x16 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x16 0x16 0x16
```

Receive:

```
0x16 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x16
```

**Test case 2**

Send:

```
0xf 0xf 0xf 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0xf 0xf 0xf
```

Receive:

```
0xf 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0
```

I have added -x option in the socat command, and I can see the correct data being displayed, so it should the receive side's problem.

P.S. All of the above tests are carried out on Mac OS X 10.9.2

Comment: IEXTEN flag in termios.c_lflag is causing this problem.
when IEXTEN is on, VDISCARD=SI (0xF) and VLNEXT=SYN(0x16) will not pass to input as mentioned in the man page of termios

Simplest way to fix this problem is pass iexten=0 to the socat command, such as:

    sudo socat -d -d pty,link=/dev/tty.vcp0,raw,echo=0,iexten=0,user=myusername,group=staff pty,link=/dev/tty.vcp1,raw,echo=0,iexten=0,user=myusername,group=staff

Answer (score 1):

IEXTEN flag in termios.c_lflag is causing this problem.

When IEXTEN is on, VDISCARD=SI (0xF) and VLNEXT=SYN(0x16) will not pass to input as mentioned in the man page of termios.

Simplest way to fix this problem is pass iexten=0 to the socat command, such as:

```
sudo socat -d -d pty,link=/dev/tty.vcp0,raw,echo=0,iexten=0,user=myusername,group=staff pty,link=/dev/tty.vcp1,raw,echo=0,iexten=0,user=myusername,group=staff
```

Comment: I was *so* hoping this would fix my issue of a socat serial-serial bridge eating uBlox control sequences (which contain 0x00 chars), but, sigh, they are still getting eaten. I am using:

 `socat /dev/ttyO0,raw,echo=0,b115200,iexten=0 /dev/ttyO4,raw,echo=0,b57600,iexten=0`

Answer (score 0):

The issue here most likely has to do with the way the device flushes it's buffers. The `cat` functions simply opens, writes the bytes, then closes the device with no regard to waiting for the data to completely run out.

Depending on what type of VCP device you are using you can configure the flush behavior so that when a device is closed it will not flush the data, instead it will just run out of the transceiver until it is done.

In a real application you would have control over this, and you could wait on the data to be received before closing the device.

A quick fix for this case is to turn up the baud rate higher so that the data leaves the device fast enough so that there is nothing in the buffer when the device is closed.

Comment: I don't think this is caused by the flush behaviour nor changing baud rate can solve this problem (at least I have try different baudrate from 9600 to 115200). Reason for this, if I sent a binary data "0x16 0x16 0x16 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x16 0x16 0x16", I can only receive "0x16 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x16". It is clearly only two consecutive 0x16 and result in one 0x16, but i am not sure what cause this behaviour.

Comment: Well I'd recommend writing an actual program for it then so you have control over the send/receive methods as well as the COM port properties. If you need assistance [this link on POSIX serial programming](http://www.cmrr.umn.edu/~strupp/serial.html) may help.

Comment: I do written a simple serial problem to send and receive the binary data, and set all those termios option which I think might be related, but the result is just the same. So to make think simple, I just ask the problem by using cat command only

Comment: I find an [Ellisys](http://www.ellisys.com/products/usbex200/) to be a useful tool for analyzing USB data transfers.

Comment: Is it possible you have these setup as XON/XOFF flow control characters, or some other escape character sequence?

Comment: Thanks for sharing Ellisys, but I am not working on real hardware right now(though later, I will). I experienced this problem on the virtual serial port (or it should be virtual terminal) created by socat, and I would expect this a problem of how to config socat, but it seems I can't find anything useful in socat's man page right now...

Comment: For the simple C program, I have turned off XON and XOFF, or basically just options.c_iflag &= ~(IXON | IXOFF | IXANY);
Actually my simple C program is written according to the site you shared.
I didn't specify and escape character explicitly, can I then assume escaping is not a cause?

Comment: Finally I find out the problem, it is caused by IEXTEN is on in c_lflag of termios, if i turn it of in my c programe, or pass -iexten=0 to socat, this problem is gone.

similar problem with the same cause can be found here: https://forums.freebsd.org/viewtopic.php?f=35&t=44882